# QGIS: Calculating the area of category overlay between 2 shapefiles

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, area, intersect

I have 2 shapefiles (A & B). The polygons in layer "B" are categorized into 8 categories (1-8) and I want to add 8 columns in layer "A" with the areal distribution of the intersection with the 8 categories from "B".

How do I approach this? The datasets are fairly large with approx. 150k rows each.
Red outline = Layer A polygons on top of Layer B (categorized).

Screenshot for clarity:

[image: Red outline = Layer A polygons on top of Layer B categorized]

Comment: Difficult to understand your question as your information is not complete and thus can't be answered. Can you post a screenshot or share sample data?

Comment: Please include relevant steps of your "experimenting" in your question.

Comment: Updated question and added screenshot

Comment: Still unclear. Which layer is which one, what should the connection between the two be, what have you tried?

Comment: Seems the screenshot description disappeared, I'll update. I've tried overlay intersection in combination with IF and case-statements.

Comment: You might look at the Overlap Analysis tool. An intersection followed by recalculating the area fields should give you the information you need with some further work to put it into 8 columns, perhaps using a pivot table and joining the work back.

Comment: Apart from what I proposed as a solution, a virtual layer that creates all 8 values at once would be a solution - however, it could become slow. I'm not sure about the query to use, so you might ask specifically about that (if interested) in a new post.

Answer (score 5):

My approach would be to:

1. Rasterize your Layer B vector layer:
   *Processing Toolbox > Vector Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster)*

   (or as it looks like it was originally a raster, use the source file)
2. Use the *Zonal Histogram* tool on the raster with your Layer A as the zones
   *Processing Toolbox > Raster > Zonal Histogram*

The red grid is my "zones" layer (Layer A).

[image]

The output is a copy of your zones geometry but with a pixel count of every raster category within each zone. The categories are added as new attribute columns.

[image]

As long as you know the pixel size of the raster, it is trivial to get the area of each category

pixel width * pixel height * pixel count

If you use a 1 m * 1 m pixel size for your raster there are no further calculations needed, the count is the area.

Comment: I reckon that this is the most optimal solution - especially as you can efficiently get the actual area (from pixel count) of each category that lies within the Layer A geometry, rather than extracting the entire vector feature that lies within the Layer A geometry, then having to get the intersection (very intensive), then calculating the area of that... and as you say it looks like the original data was from a raster.

Answer (score 2):

On layer B, use this expression to measure the area for each polygon in layer B of the overlap with polygons from layer A in category 5 (here: attribute field called `cat`). Change 5 to any other value to get the intersecting area for any other category:

```
area (
    intersection (
        $geometry, 
        collect_geometries(
            overlay_intersects(
                'A',
                $geometry,
                filter:=cat=5,  -- change category here
                limit:=-1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat complicated but it should work. It will output a temp layer with all features and attributes in A layer, and one column for each B category with the area.

**1** [Intersect](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisintersection) A and B layers.

**2** Create a virtual layer which sums and pivots the result (using [filter](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot)) to create one row per A id with a column with each B category area, and joins this to A layer.

Replace `A` with the name of your A layer, `fid` with the name of some unique identifier in A layer, `category` with the name of your category field in B layer, and all category values with the values of your categories, add rows for missing categories. Finally replace `inter` with the name of your intersect output:

```sql
select * from A a
left join 
(select     fid,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2631), 0) as area_2631,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2635), 0) as area_2635,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2640), 0) as area_2640,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2644), 0) as area_2644,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2648), 0) as area_2648,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2649), 0) as area_2649,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2650), 0) as area_2650,
        coalesce( sum(st_area(geometry)) filter(where category=2654), 0) as area_2654
from inter
group by fid) sub
on a.fid = sub.fid
```

Add the virtual layer to the map, right click and export as shape / geopackage / ...

[image]

(It should be possible to skip the intersect part and do it in the Virtual Layer but it gets so slow QGIS freezes)

Answer (score 0):

Use QGIS processing tool [Intersection (multiple)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection-multiple).

From the documentation:

Extracts the overlapping portions of features in the input and all overlay layers.

Features in the output layer are assigned the attributes of the overlapping features from both the input and overlay layers.